# If this not contains all will display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have artcles and button and category of article. If i press category "jquery" I need to have those who have category "jquery", others will display. But there are some problems. Yes i know that i display articles that have this category. But i want versa

```js
function containsJavascript() {
 var artTwo = $('.article .category');
 var art = $('.category');
     $(".article").each(function(index){
 $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('JavaScript'))").addClass('display');
});
}
function containsJquery() {
 var artTwo = $('.article .category');
 var art = $('.article');
   $(".article").each(function(index){
 $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('jQuery'))").addClass('display');
});
}
function containsCss() {
 var artTwo = $('.article .category');
 var art = $('.category');
     $(".article").each(function(index){
 $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('CSS'))").addClass('display');
});
}
```

```css
.display {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
   <div class="menu-navigation-lessons">
  <a class="nav-lessons" onclick="containsJavascript()" href="#">JavaScript</a>
  <a class="nav-lessons" onclick="containsJquery()" href="#">jQuery</a>
  <a class="nav-lessons" onclick="containsCss()" href="#">CSS</a>
</div>
<div class="article">
       <div class="title_article">
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2></a>
     <div class="description">
     <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit voluptas.
      Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos delectus! 
   Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
   <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: JavaScript </p>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
      <div class="article">
       <div class="title_article">
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
       <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: jQuery </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 
        <div class="article">
       <div class="title_article">
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
       <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Css </p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch what `article` elements have the display class on them, you must remove the class prior to assigning the class to the desired element...

```
function containsJavascript() {
     var artTwo = $('.article .category');
     var art = $('.category');
     $(".article").removeClass('display').each(function(index){
         $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('JavaScript'))").addClass('display');
     });
}
function containsJquery() {
    var artTwo = $('.article .category');
    var art = $('.article');
    $(".article").removeClass('display').each(function(index){
        $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('jQuery'))").addClass('display');
    });
}
function containsCss() {
    var artTwo = $('.article .category');
    var art = $('.category');
    $(".article").removeClass('display').each(function(index){
       $(this).has(".category:not(:contains('CSS'))").addClass('display');
    });
}
```

Or perform some sort of evaluation on the element as you loop over them and add or remove classes based on that evaluation...

```
function containsJavascript() {
     var artTwo = $('.article .category');
     var art = $('.category');
     $(".article").each(function(index){
         if ($(this).has(".category:not(:contains('JavaScript'))").length > 0){
             $(this).addClass('display');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('display');
         }
     });
}
function containsJquery() {
    var artTwo = $('.article .category');
    var art = $('.article');
    $(".article").removeClass('display').each(function(index){
        if ($(this).has(".category:not(:contains('JQuery'))").length > 0){
             $(this).addClass('display');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('display');
         }
    });
}
function containsCss() {
    var artTwo = $('.article .category');
    var art = $('.category');
    $(".article").removeClass('display').each(function(index){
       if ($(this).has(".category:not(:contains('CSS'))").length > 0){
             $(this).addClass('display');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('display');
         }
    });
}
```